# Which is correct: more expensive than "either "A or B" or "both A and B"?

Tags: comparative

The prices of A, B, and C are 10, 50, 100 dollars, respectively. In this case, which of the following is correct?

> 1. C is more expensive than both A and B.
> 2. C is more expensive than either A or B.

Some says the first is correct, others say the second is correct, so I am confused.

Comment: "Some says"  Can you clarify exactly who says they are correct? #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, idiomatic and mean the same: that C>A and C>B

Though unlikely, the first could possibly be misunderstood as C > A+B. If that was intended you could say

> C is more expensive than A and B put together.

It would be hard to misunderstand the second.  If you mean C>A or C>B you would have to say:

> C is either more expensive than A or more expensive than B

Comment: While they are both grammatical and idiomatic, I dispute your claim that C > A+B is either unlikely or a misunderstanding. In fact, I find it very difficult to parse it in a way where it doesn't mean that. As far as I'm concerned, I would say the opposite. (However, despite that, both sentences still evaluate to a true statement. 100 is greater than 10, 50, or 60.)